# How to get 0 if query returns empty set

Tags: mysql

My sql query returns an empty result and iam storing the value in a variable.But since it returns empty result nothing is stored.

```
  SET @sum_valb= (select IFNULL(SUM(review_trans.rating_given),0) as sum
        from `review_trans` where  `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  and    
  `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgeBasic
        GROUP BY `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`);
```

I want that when the result gives an empty result a zero value should get stored in @sum_valb.
I tried IFNULL but it gives an empty set only.
Please advise and help

Comment: You don't need `GROUP BY` here

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sum_valb = IFNULL((
    SELECT SUM(review_trans.rating_given)
    FROM `review_trans` 
    WHERE `review_trans`.`business_id`=businessid  
      AND `review_trans`.`user_badge_id`=@badgeBasic
), 0)
```